# Disable Next button to prevent order placement based on shipping address information in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2

We need to disable Next button on the shipping page to prevent fraud orders to certain addresses like carry forwarders and out of country. Are there any open source or paid extensions to disable order placement or disable Next button based on restricted addresses data lookup from a custom table?

What is the right place if this has to be done in a custom module and approach, without any product attributes and customer group data, since customer(s) can create new account each time they order?

Thanks